# Truncating tables between two dates (using MySQL and bash script)

Tags: mysql, sql, bash, scripting

I am trying to write a database truncate script that will truncate the tables in the database between two dates. This is a maintenance script that is run in a test setup to quickly clean things out.

The script is written in bash and calls MySQL. As previously stated this is a for testing purposes to cycle through things quickly.

I am getting an error. I suspect it may be the single quotes/tics in surrounding the dates. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
mysql -umaintainer -pfoo -Nse 'show tables' TestDatabase | while read table; do mysql -umaintainer -pfoo -Nse "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0 ; truncate table $table where date BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-31 23:59:59'" TestDatabase; done
```

Error is:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'where date BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND
>   '2015-03-31 23:59:59'' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

`truncate table` does not take a `where` clause.  It is all or nothing.  That's why it is fast.

You can do:

```
delete t from $table t
    where date BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-03-31 23:59:59';
```

If you need a fast way to delete large quantities of old rows, then you should think about partitioning.  The database drops partitions much more quickly than it deletes the same rows.

Comment: Okay ... Good to know. Thanks!